# Application icon becomes blank when folder is changed

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, desktop-application, case-sensitive

I have created an MFC application which has the icon for it as part of its resources. Now, when I place the shortcut to the application on Desktop the icon for the application appears as expected. But now when I create a folder and move this shortcut inside that folder; it becomes blank.

I am facing another situation as well; where the exe kept inside the output folder doesn't show the icon and is blank. But as soon as I change the name of the exe both the icon in the output folder aswell the desktop icon for it appears.

I am using Windows 10 and application is built using VS2008. Could you please help?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe the old icon is cached. See https://superuser.com/q/499078/1131132

Comment: the code is a basic c++ mfc dialog based application; where on OnInitDialog() I am loading the resource dll (checked it, its not null) and then load the icon from it and set it.
Observation: if I just keep the exe even inside another folder inside the output folder the icons appear. Only issue is with the output folder. Any idea how to find what wrong with that folder?

Comment: refreshing the icon db helps, but not always. Could there be a situation where some process/ service is preventing it from loading the icons? Any way to debug it?

Comment: Are you changing the icon during run time? Normally you just pick one icon and the system caches it, it doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: no @BarmakShemirani I am doing anything runtime. But, now planning to try out runtime loading of it. Do you see any issues with the runtime loading?